# Making menu active dynamically when function is called.

Tags: html, angularjs

HTML :

```
<li class="active"><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span>Dashboard</a> </li>
<li><a ng-click="viewAccount()"><span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Account</a></li>
```

I need to make Account menu as Active when function viewAccount() is called these functions are handled in same page. may be for Dashboard I can call a function dashboard() but how to make the menu active.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class`:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': menu == 'dashboard'}">
```

and in hte `viewAccount()` just set the `menu` variable.

Comment: HI this is not working. Moreover I couldn't understand your point in giving viewaccount() in menu. Function is not getting called .